# PCブラウザ(Chrome)を、一定間隔で疑似的に継続操作したい

Tags: google-chrome

**最終的にやりたいこと**
「Amazon Music」で、PCブラウザ(Chrome)を操作することなく音楽を聴き続けたい

**困っていること**
「Amazon Music」で、PCブラウザ(Chrome)を一定期間操作しないと、音楽が止まってしまいます

---

**今回の質問**
PCブラウザ(Chrome)を、一定間隔で疑似的に継続操作するにはどうすればよいですか？

**できれば知りたいこと**
userが、PCブラウザ(Chrome)を一定期間操作していない、というのはどうやって検知するのですか？
JavaScript？

Comment: 参考までに、一年ほど前に [Amazon music - stops playing due to "inactivity"](https://www.amazonforum.com/s/question/0D54P00007Ld7LzSAJ/amazon-music-stops-playing-due-to-inactivity) という事例がありますね(こちらは Echo での話ですが)。最後は Amazon Music 側で update ticket が切られた様ですが解決とはならなかった様です。

Comment: XY問題な気もしますが、デスクトップ版を使えば解決しそうです。 https://www.microsoft.com/ja-jp/p/amazon-music/9nms233vm4z9?activetab=pivot:overviewtab

Comment: デスクトップ版ダウンロードしてみましたが、一定期間操作しないと確認を求められ、再生停止する状況は同じでした